# Routing doesn't work in linux system

Tags: linux, centos, routing

I'm struggling to get the networking working working on a linux VM.  As is after the setup, I have this `ifconfig`:

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.190.144  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:febe:6707  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:be:67:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30629  bytes 3428768 (3.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 409  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 351  bytes 53232 (51.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 78  bytes 6600 (6.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78  bytes 6600 (6.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And this routing table:

```
# ip route
default via 172.19.190.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
172.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.190.144 metric 100
```

With this setup, I can ping the gateway and external internet hosts, but I cannot ping hosts on 172.19.180.x subnet, getting "host unreachable".

When I then manually do

```
# ip route add 172.19.0.0/16 via 172.19.190.1 dev eth0
```

Then everything works as expected.  I now add this line into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`:

```
172.19.0.0/16 via 172.19.190.1
```

After the reboot, my routing table looks like this:

```
# ip route
default via 172.19.190.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
172.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.190.144 metric 100
172.19.0.0/16 via 172.19.190.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
```

And I again cannot get to 172.19.180.x subnet.  The difference between this and the manual addition with `ip route add` is that the last line has `proto static metric 100` at the end, whereas with the manual way it doesn't.

What do I need to do to get everything working on a reboot?

**UPDATE:** here's my `ifcfg-eth0` file:

```
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0
UUID=.... (masked)
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.19.190.144
PREFIX=16
GATEWAY=172.19.190.1
DNS1=172.19.190.240
DNS2=172.19.190.242
```

**UPDATE2:**

If I remove the second route (`... src 172.19.190.144...`) and only leave one default, then everything work correctly. Then the question becomes: where does the second route come from and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your have two routes to `172.19/16`. Since they have the same netmask length (16 bits) the second one overrides the third one.

The third route:

```
172.19.0.0/16 via 172.19.190.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
```

was added by the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`. The second one:

```
172.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.190.144 metric 100
```

has a `proto kernel`, *so it was added by the script that configured the IP address of your interface*.

In the following I am guessing that your are using Fedora. The netmask/network  prefix that your used to configure you IP address is too wide. You need to add to the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` a line like:

```
PREFIX=24
```

**Answer to update 2:** When you add an IP address, say 1.2.3.4, to an interface, a couple of routes are added too. The exact routes depend on the tool:

- `ip addr` will force you to specify the network prefix (size of the netmask) of 1.2.3.4 or complain vehemently. If you execute: `ip addr add dev eth0 1.2.3.4/24`, you' get a `1.2.3.4/24 dev eth0` route as bonus (+ 2 routes you don't see, because they are in the `local` routing table, cf. `ip route show table local`).
- `ifconfig` will assume your network has a prefix of 24 if you do not specify a netmask and add a `1.2.3.4/24 dev eth0` route.

So a direct answer to your question is: the `PREFIX=16` line in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` caused the second route to appear.

Comment: Thanks. The distribution is CentOS 7. The /etc/sysconfig... route is my attempt to fix the issue as the routing doesn't work out of the box. I added my `efcfg-eth0` to the question.

Comment: The current configuration says that the network `172.19.190.144/16` is on the wire. If your apply the `PREFIX=24` change it will mean: only `172.19.190.144/24` are on the wire, for all other hosts in `172.19.0.0/16` send the packet to the `172.19.190.1` router.

Comment: Ah, interesting... I'll test it now. Can you please see my second update?